# How to add x and y axis titles to my facet_wrap in a for loop?

Tags: loops, facet-wrap

I made a for loop to run through every value that was a different site to demonstrate the elevation of a marsh. But I want to add axis title to my facet_wrap but I can't seem to find a way to do that. Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)
library(readr)
library(zoo)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

Elevation <- read_excel(file directory)

plot_list <- list() #storing each plot from the loop into this df

unique_sites <- unique(Elevation$Site) #setting up the array to choose every site 

for (Site_name in unique_sites) {  #reading each site from the unique_sites array 

#calculates the sum distance and elevation by choosing each sites and making a plot
Site_elevation <- Elevation %>%
  select(Site, `Distance (m)`, `Elevation (cm)`) %>%
  filter(str_detect(Site, Site_name)) %>%
  mutate(Horizontal_Distance = cumsum(`Distance (m)`)) %>%
  mutate(Vertical_Distance = cumsum(`Elevation (cm)`)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Horizontal_Distance, y = Vertical_Distance)) +
  geom_line()  +
  facet_wrap(~Site) 

  

dynamic_name <- paste0(Site_name, "_Marsh_Elevation") #adding "marsh elevation" to the site name
assign(dynamic_name, Site_elevation)  #assigning each elevation to their sites name
plot_list[[Site_name]] <- Site_elevation #putting the plots into the plot_list and assigns the name
 }
```

`grid.arrange(grobs = plot_list`) #to call all of the graphs from previous loop

I tried to do many things but nothing worked quite.